# Jquery ScrollLeft so that div's right border is always center of screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a DIV that expands as time increases after page load:

```
function scrollContainer() {
                var wave = $("#wave");
                $("body").scrollLeft(wave.width());
            }
```

I would like to re-center the browser scroll horizontally as this div expands, to make sure that the right border of this div is always centered in the screen.  Am I on the right track using scrollLeft?

Comment: Have you tried it? What type of behavior do you get? Where is the html code? The css code?  Possibly even a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what effect you're looking for, but this is an expanding div, which remains centered: http://jsfiddle.net/y0hn2Lrm/

**JavaScript**

```
var expand = function( domNode ) {

   domNode.css('width', '+=10px')

}

setInterval( expand.bind( this, $('#block') ), 1000 );
```

**CSS**

```
#block {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
}
```